# google geocode API APO/FPO AE zip codes

Tags: google-geocoding-api

Is there away to retrieve APO/FPO city types by zip code using google geocode API?

I was expecting to see an AE APO/FPO city returned when using the following call:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=09002

Here is the response of that call with no AE APO/FPO result:

```
{
   "results" : [    
{
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "090 02",
               "short_name" : "090 02",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Slovakia",
               "short_name" : "SK",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "090 02, Slovakia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.44115799999999,
                  "lng" : 21.6030916
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.349641,
                  "lng" : 21.5185274
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 49.3956347,
               "lng" : 21.5604493
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.44115799999999,
                  "lng" : 21.6030916
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.349641,
                  "lng" : 21.5185274
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "09002",
               "short_name" : "09002",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Burgos",
               "short_name" : "Burgos",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Burgos",
               "short_name" : "Burgos",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_4", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Alfoz de Burgos",
               "short_name" : "Alfoz de Burgos",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Burgos",
               "short_name" : "Burgos",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Castilla y León",
               "short_name" : "CL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Spain",
               "short_name" : "ES",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "09002 Burgos, Burgos, Spain",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.3444933,
                  "lng" : -3.6652428
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.3230844,
                  "lng" : -3.7058517
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 42.33233389999999,
               "lng" : -3.685144
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 42.3444933,
                  "lng" : -3.6652428
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.3230844,
                  "lng" : -3.7058517
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "09001",
               "short_name" : "09001",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Skvyra",
               "short_name" : "Skvyra",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Skvyrs'kyi district",
               "short_name" : "Skvyrs'kyi district",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kyivs'ka oblast",
               "short_name" : "Kyivs'ka oblast",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ukraine",
               "short_name" : "UA",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Skvyra, Kyivs'ka oblast, Ukraine, 09001",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.7594089,
                  "lng" : 29.6990729
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.705082,
                  "lng" : 29.602385
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 49.7328752,
               "lng" : 29.6642904
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 49.7594089,
                  "lng" : 29.6990729
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 49.705082,
                  "lng" : 29.602385
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      },
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Aigues-Vives",
               "short_name" : "Aigues-Vives",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Ariege",
               "short_name" : "09",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Midi-Pyrénées",
               "short_name" : "Midi-Pyrénées",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "France",
               "short_name" : "FR",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Aigues-Vives, France",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 43.013482,
                  "lng" : 1.896125
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.985824,
                  "lng" : 1.8600101
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 42.99632,
               "lng" : 1.874977
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 43.013482,
                  "lng" : 1.896125
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 42.985824,
                  "lng" : 1.8600101
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. APO/FPO, PO Boxes, CEDEX (FR), Postfach (DE), Apartado de Correos (ES), etc...

*The geocoder is designed to map street addresses to geographical coordinates*.

From [How should I format my geocoder queries to maximise the number of successful requests?](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#google-maps-api-services)

I think there used to be an explicit line about these kind of postal-only addresses in this FAQ, but it seems to not be there anymore. These don't always have a well defined location, and even when they do it's only known by the postal service, not something that could be in a public API.